# Overlapping communication and computation issue

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I am a student whose research work includes using MPI and OpenACC to accelerate our in-house research CFD code on multiple GPUs. I am using the openmpi 2.0.0 and PGI 17.5 compiler. Now I am having a big issue related to the "progression of operations in MPI". If using multiple GPUs, the communication overhead in my code is very large so that I want to overlap the communication between hosts (CPUs) and computation on devices (GPUs). However, in my case, the actual communication often starts when the computations finish. Therefore, even though I wrote my code in an overlapping way, there is no overlapping because of the openmpi not supporting asynchronous progression. Also, I have already done a lot of testing and added MPI_Test function in my code to probe, I found that MPI often does progress (i.e. actually send or receive the data) only if I am blocking in a call to MPI_Wait (Then no overlapping occurs at all). My purpose is to use overlapping to hide communication latency and thus improve the performance of my code. Can anyone provide some suggestions for this question? I would greatly appreciate your help!

Best,

Cheng

Comment: there is no progress thread in Open MPI 2.0.0. Open MPI 4.0.0 was released yesterday, and I recommend you give it a try. btw, which interconnect are you using ?

Comment: Hi Gilles, Thank you very much for your reply! It looks like OpenMPI 4.0.0 was not installed on the cluster. 100 Gbps EDR-Infiniband is used for low latency communication between compute nodes for MPI traffic (I am now using the Newriver cluster in my university: https://www.arc.vt.edu/computing/newriver/).

Comment: The good news is you can install and use Open MPI as a user in your home directory !

Comment: Gilles, Got it! I'll give it a try. Thank you so much for your help!